# What Linux archiver supports splitting archive into pieces?

Tags: linux

I need files to be <= 5GB to put on S3.

Right now I have an ugly tar / gzip / cut before upload, then cat / zcat / tar on download, but it's really ugly - and nearly every archiver should support archive splitting right?

What's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7zip can do this, it also has the best compression I've ever found (for my specific needs anyway).

Answer (score 3):

`dar` supports built-in splitting, I believe (http://dar.linux.free.fr/).

The most common answer for 'can `tar` split files' appears to be "pipe it to `split`".